# HTML .png Image As Button Shape

Tags: html, css, image, button

I doubt this is easily possible but it would be extremely useful!!!

If you don't know a .png image has transparency (see through) in it. Is there a way to create a button that is only the shape of the png image, and not the whole png-image-border. See my image for a better understanding. Here is the .png image if you want to play around with it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyXRA.png
[image]

[image]

Comment: you can convert it to svg..

Comment: @Super User Could you explain some more or post an example?

Comment: check fiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/cooy5sLy/`

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I was looking for! Last question though, how do I convert my png into that crazy string of svg?

Comment: I have already add converted code in fiddle.  you can use that

Comment: I mean how can I do this myself with other pictures, this exact picture was just for an example

Comment: You can do this using adobe illustrator image trace tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do with usemap option and adjust the **coords="140, 150, 140"** based on your requirement.

Here you can generate image map http://image-map.weebly.com/ similar like you can find many image map generator online.

```html
<map id="ImgMap0" name="ImgMap0">
    <area alt="" coords="140, 150, 140" href="http://www.link.com" shape="circle" />
</map>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="" usemap="#ImgMap0"/>
```

Comment: This works well but the problem it has is when you need to do things like "on hover" or "after clicked" type of visual changes. How would you change the button (image) on over? Loading in a new image is a bit too much I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<area>` tag.

```html
<img src="https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/flamingo.jpg" alt="" usemap="#flamingo-map-with-default">
<map name="flamingo-map-with-default" id="flamingo-map-with-default">
<area alt="Flamingo." title="Flamingo." href="https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/just-flamingo.jpg" target="_blank" shape="poly" coords="103,421,633,423,601,389,575,356,532,334,511,322,475,305,447,288,443,263,436,215,424,180,427,144,430,117,427,94,421,66,407,46,386,34,363,22,352,22,343,20,329,20,308,24,291,33,272,53,254,79,240,113,229,154,226,190,226,265,225,288,199,304,177,323,165,334,143,361">
<area alt="Not the Flamingo." title="Not the Flamingo." href="https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/no-flamingo.jpg" target="_blank" shape="default"> </map>
```

**READ MORE:**

https://html.com/attributes/area-shape/

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Comment: This works well but the problem it has is when you need to do things like "on hover" or "after clicked" type of visual changes. How would you change the button (image) on over? Loading in a new image is a bit too much I think.

Comment: Well that's the only solution in your case.